# How to download or place a copy of original tables with locked-permissions via remote connection in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, export

N00b question here: I'm still learning Oracle SQL Developer.  Although I understand how to query databases/tables remotely, I'm unable to manipulate the data due to permissions-basically I would like to download/export copies of the databases/tables so I can manipulate or adjust the data within the table.

I'm running Oracle SQL Developer on Mac OS X Yosemite and I'm unable to place a copy of the original table in my table space.  I've consulted [Oracle dox](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/sqldev/r30/SQLdev3.0_Import_Export/sqldev3.0_import_export.htm), but I believe these are dated because the GUI isn't as described.  I'd appreciate any assistance.  Thank you.

Comment: if you prefer to just type it out, this is a classic CTAS (create table as select): create table mytable as select * from <owner>.<tablename>;

Answer (score 0):

Evidently, this is how you copy tables from databases with permissions via remote connection to a local file-folder on Oracle SQL Developer (Mac OS X Yosemite):

1. Target database and expand to view tables.
2. Select desired table and right-click.
3. Hover-over 'Table' and select 'Copy'
4. A pop-up window will prompt to save copy table-name.

I've attached a screenshot below for clarification.  Thanks!

[image]